# C# Received data from SerialPort is wrong after writing

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a communication device which sends requests every two seconds through COM. Between the requests, the device waits for response. I'm building software in C# with `SerialPort`. I call an event handler for data receiving and I run a method in new thread with `while` loop which checks that the request is as expected and calls method responsible for response. The thing is, after response next received data is wrong. Here is the code:
The `SerialPortManager`:

```
class SerialPortManager : IDisposable
{
...
public void connect()
    {
        if (mSerialPort.IsOpen)
            return;
        mSerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_DataReceived);
        try
        {
            mSerialPort.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            mStatus = Status.DISCONNECTED;
            return;
        }
        if (mSerialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            mStatus = Status.CONNECTED;
            Thread tryToResponseThread = new Thread(tryToResponse);
            tryToResponseThread.Start();
        }
    }
private void tryToResponse()
    {
        while (mStatus == Status.CONNECTED)
        {
            if (mRequest.Length >= 56)
            {
                string checksum = "555555555555555580808080";
                if (mRequest.Length > 56)
                {
                    mRequest.Remove(55, mRequest.Length - 56);
                    Debug.Print("cutting");
                }
                if (mRequest.ToString().StartsWith(checksum))
                {
                    StringBuilder strToCMD = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mRequest.Length; i += 2)
                    {
                        strToCMD.Append(mRequest[i]);
                        strToCMD.Append(mRequest[i + 1]);
                        strToCMD.Append("  ");
                    }
                    StringBuilder address = new StringBuilder();
                    StringBuilder group = new StringBuilder();
                    address.Append(mRequest.ToString(24, 8));
                    group.Append(mRequest.ToString(24 + 8, 2));
                    mMainForm.appendCMDTextboxText(Environment.NewLine);
                    mMainForm.appendCMDTextboxText(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " [RX] " + address.ToString() + " " + group.ToString() + "\t");
                    mMainForm.appendCMDTextboxText(strToCMD.ToString());
                    byte[] request = ByteArrayConverter.fromString16(mRequest.ToString());
                    mRequest.Clear();
                    response(request);
                    Array.Clear(request, 0, request.Length);
                    Debug.Print("starts with checksum");
                }
                else if (mRequest.ToString().Contains(checksum))
                {
                    int indexOfChecksum = mRequest.ToString().IndexOf(checksum);
                    mRequest.Remove(0, indexOfChecksum);
                    Debug.Print("contains");
                }
                else
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    bool found = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < checksum.Length; i++)
                    {
                        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
                        int sub = mRequest.Length - checksum.Length + i + 2;
                        if (sub == mRequest.Length)
                            break;
                        s.Append(mRequest.ToString().Substring((Math.Max(0, mRequest.Length - checksum.Length + i + 2))));
                        s.Append(mRequest.ToString(0, i + 2));
                        if (s.ToString().Equals(checksum))
                        {
                            index = sub;
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (found)
                    {
                        mRequest.Remove(0, index);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mRequest.Clear();
                    }
                    Debug.Print("on start and end");
                }
            }
        }
    }
private void response(byte[] request)
    {
        Luminaire lumToResponse = mLuminaireManager.getLuminaire(request);
        if (lumToResponse == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (lumToResponse.isNotResponding())
                return;
        }
        byte[] responseMsg = lumToResponse.getWholeFrame(request);
        mMainForm.setCommandLabelForResponsingLuminaire(lumToResponse);
        mMainForm.appendCMDTextboxText(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " [TX]\t");
        string responseMsgAsString = ByteArrayConverter.toString(responseMsg).Replace("-", "  ");
        mMainForm.appendCMDTextboxText(responseMsgAsString);
        write(responseMsg, 0, responseMsg.Length);
        mSerialDataEventArgs.clearData();
    }
public void write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (mStatus == Status.DISCONNECTED || mSerialPort.IsOpen == false)
        {
            mStatus = Status.DISCONNECTED;
            return;
        }
        mSerialPort.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }
void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mStatus == Status.DISCONNECTED)
            return;
        int dataLength = mSerialPort.BytesToRead;
        if (dataLength == 0)
            return;
        byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
        mSerialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength);
        mSerialDataEventArgs.setData(data);
        mDataReceived?.Invoke(this, mSerialDataEventArgs);
    }

...
}
```

The helpser class for passing the received data:

```
public class SerialDataEventArgs : EventArgs
{

    public SerialDataEventArgs()
    {

    }
    public void setData(byte[] data)
    {
        clearData();
        mData = data;
    }
    public SerialDataEventArgs(byte[] dataInByteArray)
    {
        mData = dataInByteArray;
    }
    public void clearData()
    {
        if (mData == null)
            return;
        Array.Clear(mData, 0, mData.Length);
    }
    public byte[] mData;
}
```

And the main class:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
...
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mSerialPortManager = new SerialPortManager();
        mSerialPortManager.setPortBoudRate((int)numUpDown_SerialPortSpeed.Value);
        mLuminaireManager = new LuminaireManager();
        mSerialPortManager.mMainForm = this;
        mSerialPortManager.mLuminaireManager = mLuminaireManager;
        fixTableLayoutColumnSize(ref tl_SingleLuminaire);
        fillTheRestOfSingleLuminaireGroupBoxes();
        fillSerialPortComboBoxWithNamesOfAvailablePorts();
        mSerialPortManager.mDataReceived += new EventHandler<SerialDataEventArgs>(serialPortManager_DataReceived);
        mIsPaused = false;
    }
private void serialPortManager_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<SerialDataEventArgs>(serialPortManager_DataReceived), new object[] { sender, e });
            return;
        }
        if (mIsPaused)
            return;
        mSerialPortManager.mRequest.Append(ByteArrayConverter.toString(e.mData).Replace("-", ""));
    }
...
}
```

The communication should be like below:

```
request:  5555555555555555808080800100000001001A0006070001060031B1
response: 55555555555555558080808001000000010000808076
request:  5555555555555555808080800200000001001A0006070001060034B2
response: 555555555555555580808080020000000100008041BA
request:  5555555555555555808080800300000001001A000607000106003473
response: 55555555555555558080808003000000010000804049
```

And so on. It is just example, what the request frame should look like. As you can see, the device asks for 1,2,3,4, etc. It always asks in this order. The last four values are just checksum. What I receive after response is like:

```
request:  5555555555555555808080800200000001001A0006070001060034B2
response: 555555555555555580808080020000000100008041BA
request:  55555555555555558080808002000000000A0100000000000000BCAE
```

After response for 2, there should be an ask for 3. If I set the software to not responding, every request looks fine.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your receive function should read bytes until you get a return ('\').  You may not get all the bytes in one request so you have to append data until you get the return.

Comment: You have a threading race bug on the mSerialDataEventArgs variable, two threads modify it and a third thread reads it.  The clearData() call is not safe.  Avoid bugs like that by using as few threads as possible, you get no benefit whatsoever from using the DataReceived event handler.  So eliminate it and call Read() right after you called Write().  Repeatedly until you get the full response.

Comment: As jdweng mentioned, you will sometimes not get all the data in one burst, so you should create a buffer probably using List<byte>. And in your serialPort_DataReceived method add the bytes to the buffer. Then after adding the bytes, check in the buffer if a frame exists, then remove the frame from the buffer and then process the frame. So for example if the frame is split across two response, since everything is buffered, you will be able to find the frame in the buffer after the second response has come in.

Comment: @HansPassant It doesn't work :( I added `private void communicate()
        {
            while (mStatus == Status.CONNECTED)
            {
                if (mMainForm.mIsPaused)
                    continue;
                tryToResponse();
                if (mSerialPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    read();
                }
            }
        }
` 
It is just one thread and it doesn't work. The same result.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, so everything is okay. My COM interface is broken :( Everything is fine with both ways - DataReceived event handler and read() right after write() (no matter which solution is better in programming way). Thank you all for trying help with my case anyway!